# If i have javascript file with this implementation when will it fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i am trying to understand the following jquery code:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

  //All the JQuery code here 
  ...

})(window);
```

If there is a .js file that is included in a page with the `<script> </script>` tag when will it fire and start runing the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will run the function as soon as the contents of the `<script>` block are parsed.

Note that your code is different in an important way from:

```
$(function(jQuery) {
  // code
});
```

The above arranges for the code to run when the document is ready (the DOM is fully parsed and built).

Comment: and if i have a script that is first in the page, but that script does asynchronous calls. will this script wait until it finishs or not?

Comment: @João no - that's what "asynchronous" means.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way for me to force a script to run after another unless i place everything in the same file and use deffered objects and promises?

Comment: @João Yes, that's right - if a script starts some asynchronous operations, those will be pending while any subsequent script runs. They could coordinate through global promises or something like that.

Comment: thx i will accept ur answer as soon as i can there is a time delay for that.